# How do I use Android data binding to populate a list?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-xml, android-databinding

I can get POJOs out of my ORM (Cupboard), but I can't figure out how to write the xml to bind to such a list. All the examples are singular except for [a very brief mention of using them inside a ListView or RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#binding_data). So I've tried having a singular binding in an xml file that I "inflate" again for each item. That code follows:

```java
private void listThings() {

  LinearLayout gList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.thingList);
  gList.removeAllViews();

  SQLiteDatabase db = new CGDatabaseHandler(gList.getContext()).getReadableDatabase();
  DatabaseCompartment dbc = cupboard().withDatabase(db);

  QueryResultIterable<Thing> itr = null;
  try {
    itr = dbc.query(Thing.class).query();

    for (Thing thing : itr) {
      // use data binding to create a UI widget for each
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      ThingDocumentLabelBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
          R.layout.thing_document_label, gList, false);
      binding.setThing(thing);
      // 
      gList.addView(binding.getRoot());
    }
  } finally {
    // close the cursor
    if (itr != null)
      itr.close();
  }
}
```

I am aware that this uses a LinearLayout not a ListView or RecyclerView. What's the difference? I couldn't get anything at all to show up in a ListView. ListView also doesn't seem to support clearing the list with removeAllViews.
And here is the XML for the file thing_document_label.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <data>
    <variable
        name="thing"
        type="com.example.Thing"/>
  </data>

  <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="@{@string/thing_document_label(thing.gName, thing.dstName, thing.property3)}"
      >

  </TextView>
</layout>
```

What I get is a single TextView showing in my LinearLayout. I should be seeing six of them. I had them showing up before I started trying to do data-binding. I had just subclassed TextView and instantiated them in the same loop shown here. That worked fine, but I'm in the beginning stages of this app and I want to standardize on data-binding if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I solve the updating items of `RecyclerView` using `@BindingAdapter`:

Build base adapter:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseAdapter<Item, VH : ViewHolder> : Adapter<VH>() {
    abstract fun setItems(items: List<Item>)
}


@BindingAdapter("items")
fun <Item> updateItems(view: RecyclerView, items: List<Item>) {
    (view.adapter as? BaseAdapter<Item, in ViewHolder>)?.setItems(items)
}
```

Call on binding:

```xml
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="@{layoutManager}"
            android:adapter="@{adapter}"
            items="@{viewModel.items}"/>
```